# How to debug Ubuntu's booting errors?

Tags: ubiquity

I downloaded Ubuntu 12.10 beta1 ISO and have been trying to boot from it using a USB stick.
But every time I try to boot it freezes and all I can see is the Ubuntu logo, which gives no idea about the cause of the freeze.

I want to know if there is way such that instead of showing the Ubuntu logo, the installer would show me console output, so I could know what the actual problem is.

I know its still a beta software, but I don't want my 750 MBs to go waste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are trying Ubuntu from USB, You can enable more verbose output during booting. Do these steps:

1. In the USB drive, their should be a folder named "isolinux". (it may be "syslinux" also). Go to that folder (from your Windows or existing Ubuntu)
2. Open `txt.cfg` file inside that folder with a text editor like gedit (in Ubuntu) or Notepad (in Windows)
3. Remove the `quiet splash` words with a blank. The lines will look like this

   ```
   append  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash --
   ```

   After removing it should look like this

   ```
   append  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd.lz  --
   ```
4. Then save the file and exit Text Editor.

From now, If you boot Ubuntu from USB, you should have more verbose output showing you. Although those outputs are too fast, but can help you if booting stuck on a step.

Hope this answer  help in some degree.

Comment: my machine is way too fast...is there any way to log to file?